# How to make a button that has different parts?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button that looks similar to the Club Penguin button you click when you want to join a server.

[image]

In this picture you see that the button has three main parts, the emoji, the name, and the amount of people playing.

How can I make a button that is similar to this with multiple parts? Or would a div be better for this? Either way, I want the user to be able to click on it.

This is what I tried but i'm having difficulties.

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="button">
    <div id="first">
      Emoji
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      Name
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      Player count
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
  width:400px;
}
#first {
  float:left;
}
#second {
  float:center;
}
#third {
  float:right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rmozk80x/

Comment: If you want it to have an action, why not add `onclick` event handler like this: `<button id="button" onclick="alert('somestring')">`

Comment: Not worried about action right now, just want to make it look good like in the pic

Comment: You could use **Bootstrap Framework** for that purpose

Comment: Float: center is not a thing, it looks like it's working in your example but that's because inline elements are centered in buttons already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something similar to what you had, you might find this helpful.

inline-block display would give you more control over the flow. 
Moreover, you can make it a `div` and use `cursor: pointer;` to make hovering at it look as if it was a button.

```css
      #button {
        width:400px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 3px solid lightblue;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: darkblue;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
        font-wieght: 105%;
        font-family: Consolas;
      }

      #first {
        float:left;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      #second {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 15px;
      }
      #third {
        display: inline-block;
        float:right;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="button" onclick="alert('you clicked me!')">
    <div id="first">
      <img src="http://cdn.hercampus.com/s3fs-public/styles/full_width_embed/public/2015/04/12/persons-0004_large.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
    </div> 
    <div id="second">
      Name
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      Player count
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can remove float:center since it has no effect (because it's not a thing)

Comment: @Charlie True, I edited his code so that slipped, thanks for the comment

Comment: NP =) it looks like it's doing something because it's centered by default.

Comment: @Charlie Yup, once the `div`s were made `inline-block` I saw it, I just didn't notice it when writing the rest of the code :) thx again for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#button {
width:400px;
}

#first {
float:left;
width: 33%;
text-align: left;
background-color:
}

#second {
float:left;
text-align: center;
}
#third {
float:right;
}
```

Don't center Second, but align it left and align the contents as needed.
You can adjust the width of the first div too.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the  html element. Instead, you can add JavaScript event listeners to the divs defined containing your clickable content. That content can be styled how you choose. Below is how I interpreted your scenario.

```js
var emojiAction = document.getElementById('first');

emojiAction.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hello world');
}, false);

var nameAction = document.getElementById('second');

nameAction.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hello name');
}, false);

var playerCountAction = document.getElementById('third');

playerCountAction.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('x Players Online!');
}, false);
```

```css
#buttonContainer {
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#999;
  text-align:center;
  bottom:0;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:15px;
}

#first {
  width: calc(33% - 10px);
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px; 
}

#second {
  width: calc(33% - 10px);
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px; }

#third {
  width: calc(33% - 10px);
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <div id="first">
    Emoji
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    Name
  </div>
  <div id="third">
    Player Count
  </div>
</div>
```